# Jsoup: get all heading tags

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse an html document with Jsoup to get all heading tags. In addition I need to  group the heading tags as [h1] [h2] etc...

```
     hh = doc.select("h[0-6]");
```

but this give me an empty array.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your selector means *h-Tag with attribute "0-6"* here - not a regex. But you can combine multiple selectors instead: `hh = doc.select("h0, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");`.

**Grouping:** do you need a group with all h-Tags + a group for each h1, h2, ... tag or only a group for each h1, h2, ... tag?

Here's an example how you can do this:

```
// Group of all h-Tags
Elements hTags = doc.select("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");

// Group of all h1-Tags
Elements h1Tags = hTags.select("h1");
// Group of all h2-Tags
Elements h2Tags = hTags.select("h2");
// ... etc.
```

If you want a group for each h1, h2, ... tag you can drop first selector and replace `hTags` with `doc` in the others.

Answer (score 3):

Use **doc.select("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")** to get all heading tags.
Use **doc.select("h1")** to get each of those tags separately. See the various things you can do with a select statement in http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/jsoup/j_selector.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Scala version of the answer that uses Ammonite's syntax to specify the Maven coordinates for Jsoup:

```
import $ivy.`org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3`
val html = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://scalacourses.com").mkString
val doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html)
doc.select("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7").eachText()
```