# How to fetch all the header elements of a parsed HTML using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup

I am working on a project which is using Jsoup api's to parse an html. In another module, I receive the htmlDom object of Document class and am trying to get all the header elements. I want to extract all the Elements that are Header type `<h1, h2, ..., h6>`

I tried going through the Jsoup api, and in that, all the methods for Elements class, but couldn't find a methods which extracts for me the header elements.

Please guide me if there exists any methods that can simplify my current code for extracting header elements from an Elements collection using Jsoup.

```
Elements elementsObj = htmlDom.getAllElements();
for (Element htmlElement : elementsObj) {
    // Match and extract all the headers from other elements
    if (htmlElement.nodeName().matches("h[1-6]")) {
        headerNodeList.add(htmlElement);
    }
```

Comment: The code provided is what I am using currently and requires me to loop through all the elements in the html dom collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do to avoid looping is use Jsoup's `select` method. It allows you to select elements directly from the document and avoids any iteration. Here is another Stack Overflow post with the same question [Jsoup: get all heading tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988256/jsoup-get-all-heading-tags)

Comment: Thanks, This worked. used it as follows

`Elements elementsObj = htmlDom.select("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");`